# Drupal 7 slow page load on every request

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, cron, performance

I have problem with drupal 7 installation (I have it locally on my PC). The page loads
very slowly on every request, I have enabled Slow Queries Log and this is the output:

"Executed 626 queries in 300.88 ms. Queries exceeding 5 ms are highlighted. Page execution time was 15795.26 ms. Memory used at: devel_boot()=3.01 MB, devel_shutdown()=88.32 MB, PHP peak=92 MB."

Some more info:

The number of queries varies each request from 300-1000 !

15sec. and sometimes even more up to 70-90 seconds (but rarely) !

I have disabled the cron via "admin/config/system/cron" page.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start disabling custom modules you have one by one to see which is working slow.
Also you can check admin/reports/status for hints, what is wrong with your Drupal instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you deleted folder with some module without disabling that module, drupal trying to find that lost folder.

1. Return deleted module's folder
2. Disable module
3. Delete folder again

Answer (score 0):

First thing that matter for Drupal site performances is OS.

It is very important which OS you use on local machine. Drupal works better on UNIX based systems. For hosting Drupal site you should go with Linux platform. For developing go with Mac OS and go with Windows if you have no other choice.

Second thing is your hardware.

You should know that you must have decent hardware for good response of Drupal site on local machine. Average Drupal site using about 30-50 enabled modules and runs around 100-200 queries per page load. More complex site will rune slower and there are many ways to optimize performance of your Drupal site but that is whole another topic.

Third thing is type of modules you using.

Performance of your site is directly related with your enabled modules. Number of modules is important but it is also important what type are these modules. For instance some modules are used only in developing process so when you finish with your developing you should disable them. Math is simple. Using modules which are more complex will give you performance penalty.

Things you should do:

1. Check updates for your Drupal core and your modules
2. Update your core and modules with the latest releases
3. Run /update.php script
4. Disable developing modules and all other modules you don't need (most common modules which result some performance loss are: update manager, views UI, devel...)
5. Set up cron tasks only based on your needs
6. If you still have problems with your performances considering all above you should go on [drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/support) support forums and ask for help with specific details of your problem

Hope this helps.